# Change default editor in RStudio to notepad++

Tags: r, notepad++, rstudio

I would like to change default editor in RStudio (Windows 7) to notepad++.

I know that I should use

```
options(editor = "notepad")
```

and then run, for example:

```
mean <- edit(mean)
```

but when I type notepad++ I get this error

```
options(editor = "notepad++")
mean <- edit(mean)
Error in edit(name, file, title, editor) : 
  unable to run editor 'notepad++'
```

I Windows I can run notepad++ in console by typing "start notepad++".

I would be very grateful for help!

Here is my Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250    LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: And did you try `options(editor = "start notepad++")` ?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error.

Answer (score 12):

Ok, it was really simple:

```
options(editor = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe")
```

Sorry for the problem.

Comment: For those of you playing at home, the problem is that notepad++ is not in the PATH (while notepad is).

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else looking to this, you can permanently change the setting for *all* R workspaces by going to `‘R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site’`, where `R_HOME` is the directory it's installed.  After locating the `Rprofile.site` file, open it in Notepad++ and change the following:

```
# options(papersize="a4")
options(editor="notepad")
# options(pager="internal")
```

to:

```
# options(papersize="a4")
options(editor="C://Program Files (x86)//Notepad++//notepad++.exe")
# options(pager="internal")
```

Save the file and you're done.

Comment: I´ve tried it to use ctrl+shift+u to change case (caps lock), but it did not work.